# Position absolute nao ativar overflow: auto

Tags: html, css

Como posso fazer para a *div* absoluta(id 3) fique por cima das outras *divs* e não ative o *overflow* da *div* pai(id 2)?

```html
<div id="1" style="background: red; width: 400px">
    <div id="2" style="position: relative; background: blue; padding: 2px; width: 150px; height: 150px; overflow-y: auto;">
        <div id="3" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 0; background: #eef; padding: 2px; width: 100px; height: 300px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você define um `overflow` na `div`, ela restringe tudo que está nela à sua área, pois é pra isso que serve o `overflow`. Mesmo colocando elementos com `position absolute`, eles ficarão confinados à área da `div`. Portanto não faz sentido colocar uma `div` maior sem querer que ela respeite a regra do `overflow`.

A solução é tirar a `div 3` da `div 2` e posicionar o `right` usando `calc` subtraindo a largura da `div 1` pela largura total da `div 2` (`width` + `padding`), e setando também a `div 1` com `position relative`:

```html
<div id="1" style="background: red; width: 400px; position: relative;">
    <div id="2" style="position: relative; background: blue; padding: 2px; width: 150px; height: 150px; overflow-y: auto;">
    </div>
     <div id="3" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: calc(100% - 154px); background: #eef; padding: 2px; width: 100px; height: 300px"></div>
</div>
```