# Position absolute dentro de um overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
  <div class="prisoner">o</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc; 
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.prisoner {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #fa0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
}
```

Neste caso, teria como deixar o prisoner visivel (quando ultrapassar os limites da div box), mesmo ele estando dentro de uma overflow hidden?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/268987/8063

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infelizmente não tem como. Você pode conferir direto na documentação da W3C

> **Overflow** The overflow property specifies whether content of a block container element is clipped when it overflows the element's
>   box.

- hidden - The content is clipped and no scrollbars are provided.

Ou seja tudo que ultrapassar o limite do *box* vai ser *clippado* (cortado)

https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/overflow

Até fiz um teste colocando um Pseudo Elemento no próprio Box e mesmo assim ele foi *clippado*

EDIT: Vc pode remover o `overflow: hidden;` no evento `:hover` por exemplo

Teste com `::after` e `:hover`

```css
body {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
  .box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc; 
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}
.box::after {
    content: "o";
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #fa0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="prisoner">o</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

se for no centro que vc quer, pode ser assim, usando o position absolute.

```
<style>
    #fora{
        width: 500;
        height: 500;
        background-color: #34495e;
        position: relative;
    }

    #dentro{
        width: 50;
        height: 50;
        background-color: #e74c3c;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }
</style>

<div id="fora">
    <div id="dentro">

    </div>
</div>
```