# Como estilizar o scroll de uma div

Tags: css

olá, gostaria de saber como eu estilizo a barra de rolagem dessa div, e outra coisa, ao passar o nome sobre os nomes o efeito hover dele abre uma div para esquerda, depois que eu coloquei nessa div que segura os nomes `overflow: auto` não funciona o efeito hover dela que seria mostrar a outra div, quando eu tiro o `overflow: auto` funciona normalmente, alguém pode me ajudar ? oque estou fazendo de errado ? http://prntscr.com/ip0jju

```css
#usuarios {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 364px;
  max-height: 364px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 3px solid #c9c9c9;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar #usuarios {
  width: 10px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button #usuarios {
  width: 10px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track #usuarios {
  width: 10px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece#usuarios {
  width: 10px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb #usuarios {
  width: 10px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner #usuarios {
  width: 10px;
}

 ::-webkit-resizer #usuarios ul li {
  position: relative;
}

#usuarios ul li:first-child {
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#usuarios ul li:last-child {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

#usuarios ul li a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #000;
}

#usuarios ul li .admin {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

#usuarios ul li:hover .admin {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#usuarios ul li:hover a {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#usuarios ul li:hover a span {
  opacity: .95;
}

#usuarios ul li a span {
  display: block;
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .60;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#usuarios ul li .on {
  color: green;
}

#usuarios ul li .aus {
  color: orange;
}

#usuarios ul li .off {
  color: #ff0000;
}

#usuarios ul li a .on {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: green;
}

#usuarios ul li a .aus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: orange;
}

#usuarios ul li a .off {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

#usuarios ul li ul li .perfil {
  display: none;
}

#usuarios ul li:hover ul li .perfil {
  display: block;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  left: -215px;
  top: -35px;
  width: 200px;
}

#usuarios ul li:hover ul li .perfil .box_perfil {
  width: 196px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="usuarios" class="usuarios align_right border-radius rgba">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="on admin border-radius">Admin <span class="on align_right">ON</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="perfil">
            <div class="box_perfil"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="on">Amanda <span class="on align_right">ON</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="on">Joana <span class="on align_right">ON</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="on">Pedro <span class="on align_right">ON</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="on">Bruna <span class="on align_right">ON</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="on">Lohana <span class="on align_right">ON</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="on">Julio <span class="on align_right">ON</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="aus">Amanda <span class="aus align_right">AUS</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="aus">Felipe <span class="aus align_right">AUS</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="aus">Igor <span class="aus align_right">AUS</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="off">Lucas <span class="off align_right">OFF</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="off">Amanda <span class="off align_right">OFF</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="off">Bruna <span class="off align_right">OFF</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="off">Jéssica <span class="off align_right">OFF</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: minha dúvida não é só essa

Comment: Altera somente com a parte dos efeitos @Bruno

Comment: @Bruno, acredito que você tem duas dúvidas bem diferentes, seria legal fazer uma outra pergunta sobre o `hover` pra ficar com as respostas mais focadas

Comment: se eu fazer a pergunta sobre o scroll vão falar que eu estou duplicando, eu ja olhei essa pergunta que ele falou e não resolveu o meu problema sobre o efeito hover, estilozo o scroll porem ficou sem hover

Comment: Cara para o scroll bar vc pode usar esse plugin: https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/ projeto deles no Git: https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll agora sobre a outra dúvida, sugiro que vc poste uma nova pergunta sobre esse problema  em particular. Outra coisa, o Scroll Bar tem uma série de limitas de CrossBrows, resumindo quase não vai funcionar em lugar nanhum

Comment: Talvez isso possa esclarecer o problema da div: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/269014/8063