# Como usar css para sobrepor metade de outra DIV que está com overflow sem usar position: fixed?

Tags: html, css, posicionamento

Eu gostaria de saber como usar CSS para colocar uma DIV sem `position:fixed` sobre a metade de outra que esta com `overflow`.

Eu gostaria que ficasse assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código de exemplo que estou usando é:

```css
.div1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.div2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000;
    margin-left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
 <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Veja esta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/269014/8063

Comment: Tudo que vc colocar dentro de uma div com overflow ficará restrita à área da div. Neste caso vc deverá rever a estrutura e posicionar a div de outra forma. Não precisa usar fixed, mas outra forma em que a div fique onde vc deseja em relação a outra.

Answer (score 1):

Um não deve pertencer ao outro, mas tem que testar quando estiverem do lado de outros elementos.

```css
.div1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000;
    margin-left: 70px;
    position:absolute;
}

.div2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Da para fazer sim, sem mexer em nada do seu código. Apenas criei um pseudo elemento `::after` na `div1`

Veja o código, e use o scroll horizontal para vc ver que o `::after` está na metade da div e não é afetado pela rolagem.

Como falei não mexi no HTML nem no CSS, só criei o elemento `::after` com o estilo.

```css
.div1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.div2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000;
    margin-left: 70px;
}
.div1::after {
    content: "";
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 70px;
    top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```