# Problema com overflow de elemento pai afetando a visibilidade de um elemento filho com "position: absolute"

Tags: css

Ah, tem várias algumas coisinhas no CSS que as vezes me estressam!

Tenho um elemento pai responsável por listar vários itens. E dentro desses itens, quando passo o mouse em determinado link, exibi-se um diálogo (ou balão) que mostra umas informações. E esse balão está com `position: absolute`, com o cenário bem próximo a esse:

```css
    .pai {

        background-color: #ccc;
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 300px;
    }

    .item {
        background-color: lightblue;
        height: 50px; 
        position: relative;
    }

    .item a{
        padding: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #049;
    }

    .dialogo {
        display: none;
    }

    .item a:hover+.dialogo {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #ccc;
        padding: 15px;
        z-index: 1000
    }
```

```html
<div class="pai">
    <div class="item">
        <a>passe o mouse aqui</a>
        <div class="dialogo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde molestias vel ducimus, delectus recusandae veritatis asperiores reiciendis dicta a, voluptatibus quaerat quis in, sunt quas! Aspernatur dolore odit non illo!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a>passe o mouse aqui</a>
        <div class="dialogo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde molestias vel ducimus, delectus recusandae veritatis asperiores reiciendis dicta a, voluptatibus quaerat quis in, sunt quas! Aspernatur dolore odit non illo!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a>passe o mouse aqui</a>
        <div class="dialogo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde molestias vel ducimus, delectus recusandae veritatis asperiores reiciendis dicta a, voluptatibus quaerat quis in, sunt quas! Aspernatur dolore odit non illo!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a>passe o mouse aqui</a>
        <div class="dialogo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde molestias vel ducimus, delectus recusandae veritatis asperiores reiciendis dicta a, voluptatibus quaerat quis in, sunt quas! Aspernatur dolore odit non illo!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Observe que, ao passar o mouse sobre a `.item a`, o `.dialogo` aparece cortado, pelo `overflow:scroll` ou `overflow: hidden`.

[image: Problema com overflow e position absolute]

Ou seja, parece que o `z-index` combinado com `position: absolute` possuem algum tipo de conflito, pois, mesmo com o `z-index`, parte do diálogo é ocultado.

Existe algum jeito de diblar essa chatisse no CSS?

Tem alguma forma de resolver, sem eu ter que alterar tudo que já fiz ou
alterando o mínimo possível?

**Observação**: Gostaria de resolver só com CSS, sem Javascript, por favor.

Comment: A parte do `dialog` é cortada devido ao `max-height` do elemento `pai`, naum?

Comment: @MagicHat então, mas considerando que eu estou usando um `z-index` maior, esperava um comportamento diferente.

Comment: O `z-index` vai fazer a parte dele, agora quando você define a altura máxima de 1 elemento, os atributos capazes de manipular esse comportamento são de de altura...

Comment: @MagicHat não só isso. Se o elemento por exemplo não tiver um Width definido e tiver `overflow: hidden`, ele vai ocultar o absolute dentro dele... Isso é chatão.... queria que o CSS tivesse um jeito mais fácil de resolver isso.

Comment: "Ocultar o absolute dentro dele(it self?)...!!!", man se virou ocultista? Do que se tá falando veio? Qual exatamente é o comportamento esperado? kkkk[

Comment: @MagicHat geralmente, o `z-index` combinado com o absolute faz o que? ele coloca aquele elemento com posição acima das outras (como se fosse uma camada).

Comment: Considere acrescentar o `;` após declarar o atributo desejado. (kkkkk)

Comment: Sei lá aqui num tá cortando naum...

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Position absolute nao ativar overflow: auto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268987/position-absolute-nao-ativar-overflow-auto)

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que `position: absolute;` não vai afetar a altura do box-model do elemento pai, o corte é por simplesmente o elemento aparecer no limite da altura, não tem o que resolver nisto, talvez o caminho seria mudar a abordagem.

Só pra constar `z-index` não afeta o elemento para vazar para fora do overflow, ele é para você controlar o posicionamento `z` dos elementos, o que você deve fazer é definir quem será o elemento `relativo`, assim os elementos com `absolute` irão trabalhar a partir dele, para resolver isto crie um elemento avô, um pai e um neto.

O elemento avô, deve ser o elemento **sem overflow** com `position: relative;` e do seu elemento `.item` também, o unico que pode conter o relative é o avô, assim:

```css
    .avo {
        position: relative;
    }

    .pai {
        background-color: #ccc;
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 300px;
    }

    .item {
        background-color: lightblue;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .item a{
        padding: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #049;
    }

    .dialogo {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #ccc;
        padding: 15px;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    .item a:hover+.dialogo {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="avo">

    <div class="pai">
        <div class="item">
            <a>passe o mouse aqui</a>
            <div class="dialogo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde molestias vel ducimus, delectus recusandae veritatis asperiores reiciendis dicta a, voluptatibus quaerat quis in, sunt quas! Aspernatur dolore odit non illo!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a>passe o mouse aqui</a>
            <div class="dialogo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde molestias vel ducimus, delectus recusandae veritatis asperiores reiciendis dicta a, voluptatibus quaerat quis in, sunt quas! Aspernatur dolore odit non illo!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a>passe o mouse aqui</a>
            <div class="dialogo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde molestias vel ducimus, delectus recusandae veritatis asperiores reiciendis dicta a, voluptatibus quaerat quis in, sunt quas! Aspernatur dolore odit non illo!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a>passe o mouse aqui</a>
            <div class="dialogo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde molestias vel ducimus, delectus recusandae veritatis asperiores reiciendis dicta a, voluptatibus quaerat quis in, sunt quas! Aspernatur dolore odit non illo!</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

---

No entanto ainda sim existe um problema nessa abordagem toda, conforme posiciona o scroll, ou aumenta o conteudo, os elementos com `position: absolute;` vão mudar de lugar, então talvez a unica abordagem para evitar tudo isso seja fazer dinamicamente com JavaScript deixando o popup/tooltip se ajustar baseado no `getBoundingClientRect()` compensando com o elemento "pai" as posições X e Y (e talvez com o `scrollTop` também entrando na operação matematica para obter o resultado)